# ComponentActivator: could not instantiate Repository","ExceptionType":" Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.ComponentActivatorException

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, castle-windsor

I am using Windsor Castle in MVC5 application. After deploying the web service to IIS, I am getting the following error

{"$id":"1","Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"ComponentActivator: could not instantiate XXXRepository","ExceptionType":" Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.ComponentActivatorException"

If I run the above using VS inbuilt server, its working fine.

Any suggestions/ pointers will be highly appreciated.

Comment: the inner exception will tell you what the underlying problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above problem is solved by adding EntityFramework.SQLServer.dll file

Comment: I have this dll added to projects and I can see it on the server (Azure), but I still get an error. App works fine locally.
App throws exception while starting executing SomeContext:base("SomeContext"). The inner exception is as in OP title.